# Run music21 on full processor power

Tags: python, dataset, multicore, cpu-cores, music21

I am trying to create dataset by extracting only specific songs from larger [dataset](http://colinraffel.com/projects/lmd/) . 
By specific I mean songs only with two instruments where one is from keyboard family and another is from string family. Simplified code looks like this:

```
    for midi_file_path in Path(dir_path).glob('**/*.mid'):
    try:
        song = converter.parse(midi_file_path)
        parts = instrument.partitionByInstrument(song)
        if parts:
            if len(parts) == 2:
                if (parts.parts[0].id in keyboard_instruments and parts.parts[1].id in string_instruments) or \
                        (parts.parts[1].id in keyboard_instruments and parts.parts[0].id in string_instruments):
                                print(midi_file_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception ", midi_file_path,  e)
        pass
```

This process takes a lot of time, and I would like to optimise it. 
The main **question is why processor does not run on full power**, but only around 17%. The last version of [music21](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/releases) says - *"Feature Extraction runs multicore by default"* .

[image]

Comment: you're not doing feature extraction (the .features module).  Look at the docs for `common.runParallel()` to see ways to multiprocess the conversion process.